# Data stored in Mongodb database either with or without credentials while authentication is enabled

Tags: mongodb, authentication, mongoose, mongodb-compass, local-database

- I am using the latest versions of Mongodb (And Mongoose), Angular, Express, And Nodejs for my application.
- I downloaded the installable .msi file to install it on my WINDOWS machine.
- I have followed the instructions on Mongodb DOCS and made some changes to get database Authentications enabled for a `local Database`.

***The Problem is When I connect either with username and pass or without them the connections get established! and data are stored in both cases***

I tried the steps below:

1. Opened `Mongodb Compass Shell` and `CONNECT`
2. Used Mongosh *in the dark strip at the bottom of the GUI*
3. Run `use admin`
4. Run `db.dropAllUsers()` - to clean the users data
5. Run

```
db.createUser(
{
user: "Admin",
pwd: "myNewPassword",
roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "posts" } ]
}
)
```

-to create a username and password and assign a role (based on Mongodb Docs)
6. Disconnected from the database via GUI Menu bar (Connect Button > Disconnect)
7. Didn't find the `/etc/mongod.conf` path so I managed to find a so-called file somewhere else(no idea if it is the right one):
`C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin\mongod.cfg`
8. I entered

```
security:
  authorization: "enabled"
```

Under #security: section

9. I tried both cases
   `mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/posts")`
   and
   `mongoose.connect("mongodb://Admin:myNewPassword@localhost:27017/posts")`

Both were connected successfully and in either cases data were stored in Databse!

*to be clearer My expected behavior was that the connection would have been failed in the first case! And data not stored in the database
*

Thanks!

Comment: I followed the tutorial below:
https://www.mongodb.com/features/mongodb-authentication

Comment: You can always connect to a MongoDB even without credentials. But without authentication you can run only harmless commands like `db.help()` or `db.listCommands()` or `db.getMongo()`

Comment: No, you did not follow the tutorial. You must grant the role from db `admin`, see [Built-In Roles](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/built-in-roles/): *MongoDB provides the built-in database user and database administration roles on every database. **MongoDB provides all other built-in roles only on the `admin` database.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found where the problem is! I had not restarted the *MongoDB Server* to have authorizations take effects! So I restarted MongoDB server in windows Services!